# ios Branch.io Passing google/facebook campaign and channel in session parameters

Tags: ios, google-ads-api, branch.io

We use Universal campaign in Google Adwords and usual Facebook campaign for apps. We don't pass branch links for these campaigns. In branch analytics I see installs and conversion events for these campaigns. But also I would expect parameters 'channel' and 'campaign' within

```
Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions) { (parameters, error) in
    // Expect 'channel' and 'campaign' parameters here
}
```

For the search campaign in Google Adwords we use the branch link and receive the campaign.

Answer (score 1):

This is Vatsal, from [Branch.io](https://Branch.io).

As per our new integrations with Google Adwords and Facebook, you do not need any Branch links for **App Install ads** for attribution. Hence, there is no deep linking attribution and will not print the campaign and channel values in the SDK. As this attribution is server based, you can get it via two ways:

1. [Webhooks](https://docs.branch.io/pages/exports/ua-webhooks/):These fire a webhook to your API on the install/open events passing the campaign and other analytics tags to your servers in near-realtime.
2. [Data Exports API](http://%20https://docs.branch.io/pages/exports/api-v3/): This enables you to download the CSV for all the installs and all the other possible events.

Hope this helps! Please let us if you have more questions at integrations@branch.io

Comment: But is it possible to get the metadata I setup on Branch, if I'm using the Branch Ads Links on my Facebook campaigns?